# HEX String to Chinese String

Tags: c#, string, hex, cjk

I have the following code to convert from HEX to ASCII.

```
//Hexadecimal to ASCII Convertion
private static string hex2ascii(string hexString)
{
    MessageBox.Show(hexString);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <= hexString.Length - 2; i += 2)
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

input hexString = D3FCC4A7B6FABBB7

output return = ÓüÄ§¶ú»·

The output that I need is 狱魔耳环, but I am getting ÓüÄ§¶ú»· instead.
How would I make it display the correct string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert the hex string to a `byte[]`, e.g. using code at [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c).  Then use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myArray)` (use proper encoding, might not be Unicode, but judging from your example it is a 16-bit encoding, which, incidentally, is not "ASCII", which is 7-bit) to convert it to a string.

Comment: oh god! i feel retarded now... haha
Thank you kind sir, this worked!